# How to resolve wrong URL using Spring MVC url mapping

Tags: html, spring-mvc, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm writing a controller that handle url like abc.com/detail/*-detail-{id}, "*" mean that user can input anything in that position (such as product name) and my controller using id to get product detail. My problem is that when user input wrong product name, how can I fix my URL to product name corresponding with the id?

```
@Controller
public ProductController{

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/detail/*-detail-{productId}")
    public String getProduct(@PathVariable int productId, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        Product product = productService.getProduct(productId);
        model.addAttribute("product", product);
        return "detail";
    }
}
```

Example:
productId = 1 => product-name

With request URL:

abc.com/detail/product-name-detail-1 => product 1

abc.com/detail/product-x-detail-1 => product 1 => change URL to abc.com/detail/product-name-detail-1

Thank for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/detail/{productName}/detail-{productId}")
public String getProduct(@PathVariable("productId") int productId,@PathVariable("productName") String productName, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    Product product = productService.getProduct(productId);
    if(!product.getProductName().equals(productName)){
      return "detail/"+product.getProductName()+"/detail-"+productId;
   }else{
      model.addAttribute("product", product);
      return "detail";
   }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, That is a way to resolve my problem. Are there any way to do that without redirect to the correct one, because if we use redirect, we need to request two time.